# Programmatically check when google sheets spreadsheet was last updated

Tags: python, io, version-control, timestamp, google-sheets-api

I am starting to pull data from multiple shared spreadsheets on google sheets and this works fine. Currently I have to read in the whole spreadsheet and process the data to see if any updates have been made to it. How can I programmatically (in Python 3.9) get a timestamp of the last update to a google sheet?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I thought that "Files: get" of Drive API might be able to be used. In your situation, when googleapis for python is used, how about the following sample script? About `service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)`, in this case, you can see it at [Quickstart for python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python). In this case, `fileId` is the spreadsheet ID.

```py
service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds) # Please use your authorization script here.
fileId = "###" # Please set spreadsheet ID.
res = service.files().get(fileId=fileId, fields="modifiedTime").execute()
print(res)
```

By this sample script, the last modified time is retrieved.

If you will use `requests`, how about the following sample script? In this case, please use your access token.

```py
fileId = "###" # Please set spreadsheet ID.
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer ###your access token###"}
res = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?fields=modifiedTime", headers=headers)
print(res.text)
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: This looks thorough but is for google drive, not google sheets. Would this work for a google sheet that's not in google drive?

Comment: @Alex Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Would this work for a google sheet that's not in google drive?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Google drive and Google sheets are two separate tools with separate apis. I hadn't realized that you can access all google sheets from google drive. This was my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood it. When a Google Spreadsheet is created, it is put in Google Drive. By this, the last modified time of the Spreadsheet can be obtained using Drive API.